# How to call Ajax functions without onclick/onkeyup/onchange etc

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jqmobi

I am trying to include a .php file that will generate a form for me by picking out questions from a MySQL database. I've found numerous ways to call this function that I have called getQuestions() with 1 parameter (page number). I've seen drop down menus that will execute my php file using onchange, or buttons (onclick) etc. But is there a way to use my function without these? I just want it to automatically load with the rest of the page without any unnecessary interactions.

Don't know if this matters but my page is made in jQuery Mobile so it should only be visible when the correct page/div-id is active.

```
function getQuestions(str)
    { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("page_1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","generate_questions.php?p="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

These are the functions I have tried to use to view the .php within the rest of the HTML (without success)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    getQuestions(1);
                    });
                    </script>


window.onload = function() {
                    $("#page_1").load(getQuestions(1));
                    }

window.onload = function() {
                    getQuestions(1);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I solved my problem by assigning the php code to a smaller div than originally planned. I can't assign it to the page id, but to a smaller div within the page. The odd thing is it seems I can't really generate new div's within the php code either, so that sort of limits it's usage.

Answer (score 4):

You can use document ready event to load rest of the content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // your code
 });
```

Comment: That goes in the header right?

But would this mean I have no real control over where exactly in the page/div-id my .php will generate the question, or does my .php file need to generate the whole page on it's own?

Comment: @TomErikHøvring That code can go anywhere it's valid to have a `<script>` tag; it binds to the DOM ready event, so won't execute the code until the DOM is ready. I don't know enough about jQuery mobile to give you any more advice, though.

Comment: you can put this code anywhere on your page: header, body or in div inside body. Just surround it with <script/> block. you will control where to put contents inside ajax call function, do have it already?

Comment: Got it to work, but the .php site is the only thing that shows, keeps ignoring my other html code for that page/div-id like headline and footer etc. Seems I have to generate the whole page within .php. Still says I am on index.html#page_1 though, and the css works until I refresh. Appreciate all your help though, just have to keep hammering at it until it works :)

Comment: could you show us your ajax function? it seems that it is not ajax or you handling result in not correct way

Comment: There it is. Seems it still lets me change pages by manipulating the #page parameter after .html without losing any data - so something has to be right in all this madness.

Comment: Also if I view source code I can see the whole .html code. The url is /index.html#page_1 but it does not show anything from <div id="page_1"> except from the stuff from the .php site.

Comment: Your code is correct for regular web sites, but it look like jquery.mobile handles all ajax requests and page redirects in its own manner (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)

Comment: Oh nice, that will hopefully help me progress! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do that on `Window.onload or document.ready` event.

Answer (score 1):

Hello following way you can call the code without click or change

just write down the function name between script tag and create that function after call the function.

Comment: I have tried this, but then it will only go to the .php site and leave the original site. Unless I am doing it wrong :P